# How to put a \urcorner around some symbol?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Like this:

[image: Example function]

Tried `P_{30:20^{\ulcorner}}`, but I want the `\ulcorner` to be more near to the text.

Comment: Manually, you can accomplish it "nearer to the text" with `$P_{30:20^{\!\!\urcorner}}$`; however, are there any added requirements, for example on the width of the horizontal bar, as shown in your image?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, the horizontal bar should be as wide as the symbol been covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `actuarialangle`, see the “[Comprehensive list of symbols](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)”, Table 251; for the package documentation, [`texdoc actuarialangle`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/actuarialangle/README)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{actuarialangle}

\begin{document}

\[
P_{30{:}\actuarialangle{20}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Made to work in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel,stackengine}
\def\xyz#1{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackon[1\LMpt]{$\SavedStyle#1$}{\rule{\wd0}{.5\LMpt}}%
  \rule[-1\LMpt]{.5\LMpt}{\dimexpr\ht0+2.5\LMpt}}}
\begin{document}
$P_{30:\xyz{20}}\quad
\xyz{1234}\quad
\scriptscriptstyle\xyz{567890}$
\end{document}
```

[image]